# gradle combining multiple build script dependecies

Tags: gradle

gradle multiple build script dependencies
We am in the process from transacting my our build scripts from ant to gradle. The ant build is configured the old way without using ivy and getting the dependencies from a lib folder.
We have a number of custom ant tasks packaged in jar. To run the tasks in that jar we also need some other third parties dependencies from the same lib folder.

Being a complex build we cannot afford to move everything in one go and would rather move one bit at a time as we find some time to do it.
I was able to run those custom ant tasks from the gradle build but I am having problems accessing classes from or tasks jars in my gradle build scripts.

In the build script section we have a class path entry needed for artifactory plugin and I tried to add some more class path entries to make our local libs available.

```
buildscript {
    ….
    dependencies {
        // This dependency below is needed by artifactory plugin which we download 
        classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:3.0.1"
    }
    ….
}
```

I tried lots of combinations but I could not get it to work. What we want is to be able to do something like below:

```
buildscript {
    …
    dependencies {
        classpath {
            ["org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:3.0.1",
            fileset(dir: "${antBuildDir}/customTasks", includes: 'myTasks.jar'),
            fileset(dir: "${antBuildDir}/lib", includes: '*.jar')]
        }
     }
    …
}
```

Any idea about how can I address this or any other suggestions if you think I am on the wrong path.
Thank you in advance.
Julian

Comment: See "51.4.4. File dependencies" in the [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html) for how to declare file dependencies. Keep in mind that if you convert the Ant build target-by-target rather than doing things the Gradle way, you'll end up with an Ant build in disguise, and won't be able to benefit from many of Gradle's advantages. (Occasionally using an Ant task where no equivalent Gradle task/plugin exists is fine.)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I read that chapter numerous times before decided to post this. Maybe I did not make it clear but what I am interested in chapter 60.5. External dependencies for the build script.
What we want is to be able to add external dependencies for the build script from both artifactory and the file system

Comment: You just need to combine the information from these two chapters: `classpath fileTree(...)`. There is no `fileset` method in Gradle (where did you get this from?).

Comment: That was my mistake. I took the fileset from the classpath definition of an ant.taskdef(..) and did not realize that it was in fact ant specific way rather than gradle. As soon as I added two classpath entries in that build script dependencies section one pointing to arifactory and one using a fileTree/files everything work very well. Please post your comment as an answer so I can accept it. Thanks a lot.